# In C++11, can I use override specifier on an explicitly defaulted destructor?

Tags: c++11

And if so, what would be the syntax?

This does not compile with g++ -std=c++0x:

```
class B {
public: 
    virtual ~B() {} 
}; 

class A : public B {
public: 
    ~A() = default override; 
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`override` before `= default` as following;

```
class B {
public: 
    virtual ~B() {} 
}; 

class A : public B {
public: 
    ~A() override = default; 
};
```